# ant build.xml in SCons

Tags: ant, scons

I am making use of a library project which uses *ant* to build. My project however is using *SCons* because I need a far more complex build setup. Now I would like to use *ant* via *SCons* but NOT impose the problematic *CLASSPATH* issues and installation that *ant* requires.
So I am currently thinking of writing a `build.xml` parser, which turns the *ant* into *SCons* tasks.
Does anyone know whether this has been done before?

Comment: I never heard of scons before, must take a look sometime. My initial reaction is that the Java space already has enough build technologies. ANT and Maven predominately. Newer technologies (like Gradle) only exist because they play nice with Maven's repository infrastructure. This seems to be the best way to collaborate between projects, share from a trusted source of binaries instead of struggling to build other peoples code.

Comment: I know I'm not answering the question, which is why I keep this as a comment. The Scons wiki has an excellent evaluation of the state of Java and challenges of "doing java" http://www.scons.org/wiki/JavaStrategy

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no such parser in existence, which I partly believe is because there is great difference in how SCons and ant work. Especially when it comes to dependency resolution. It should be possible, but the translated file output will be very little SCons like, quite unreadable and probably quite difficult to maintain. Which pretty much defeats the whole reason to use SCons in the first place.

Since the library already uses ant, it would probably be a good idea to just incorporate the running of ant into SCons. If SCons can use ant, then you won't have to maintain the library build script (unless it is you that maintain the ant also)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: http://geosoft.no/development/android.html?  We're also looking at converting an ANT based android build into our over-arching SCONS build and this looks like a good starting point.